# Generating Combinations and Variations with a twist c#

Tags: c#, combinations, permutation

This question is on the subject of Variations without Repetition (Yes I did research, I just need some insight on a problem that is very unique to my task).

Essentially I have been tasked with writing a routine that finds all possible variations of a 5 digit string then adds those strings to a list. The tricky thing about my problem is that the first 3 digits in the string are octal numbers 0-7 and the last two digits in the string are an alpha numeric representation 0-7 or A-Z* (excluding the letters I and O).

Through my research I have been able to come up with separate combinations of the octal set and the alphanumeric set. I also display the combinations to the debugger, just to make sure that it is working.

```
static void Main()
{
    string[] octalset = { "0", "1","2","3","4","5","6","7" };

    List<string> tracknum15 = new List<string>();
    List<string> tracknum19 = new List<string>();

    var v = new Variations<string>(octalset,3,GenerateOption.WithRepetition);

    foreach (var vv in v)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Join("", vv));
        tracknum15.Add(vv);
    }

    string[] alphanumericset = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };

    var a = new Variations<string>(alphanumericset, 2, GenerateOption.WithRepetition);

    foreach (var aa in a)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Join("", aa));
    }
}
```

My main issue is that I cannot figure out how to generate one list of combinations where the first three digits are octal and the last two are alphanumeric. The second issue is that I am having trouble adding my combinations to a list after I have generated them.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you want to create every possible string starting with 3 octs and then 2 elements from the group 0-7 A-Z excluding I and O.

This sounds like you will need 2 loops, one creating each oct number from 000 to 777 and a second inner loop adding your 2 element part. See here for nested loops, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_nested_loops.htm

string.Join("", vv) is not required, just do:  (string) vv

Comment: So if I nest the for loop for the alphanumeric characters, that will allow me to find every combination of the of the Octal set (000-777) and the Alphanumeric Set (00-ZZ) and display them as one string? I already generate a list of all the octal and all the alpha combinations separately. Also, I tried to use that cast without join("" , vv) and it gives me an error .

Comment: yeah, you can always create 1 octal, like 000, and then all alphanumerics for it, then you do the second octal and do all alphanumerics again

Comment: Okay, in the code that I posted above The first foreach loop creates the octal numbers. After that I am having trouble syntax wise on how to say..... now that I have 000 I want to display every combination of the alphanumeric characters that go with it. Can you clarify a little bit on how you would go about doing that in code?